# Do you know a text editor to work on both Windows and macos, which supports writing from right to left?

Tags: windows, text-editor, macos

My research so far yielded the following results:

VSCode - support RTL fonts but not writing from right to left.

NP++ - Does support RTL, but Is not compatible with MACOS.

Sublime Text - support RTL fonts but not writing from right to left.

Atom - RTL?? but anyways - end of life was declared.

UltraEdit - maybe, but cost a lot.

EditPad/EditPlus/EmEditor - maybe, but only windows and some are not free.

Comment: Maybe Brackets or Textmate or SublimeText.